# Why can I cancel out the matrix in the middle

Tags: matrix-equations

I was given an example from my teacher when he does something like

$$A^TC^{-1}A \gt B^TC^{-1}B \implies A^TA \gt B^TB$$

Where A and B are vectors.

I am curious on how can the inversed matrix C in the middle got cancelled out?

Comment: If $C$ isn't a positive multiple of the identity, you can't

Comment: Maybe they were under some operator (like trace, or something else)?

Answer (score 6):

If that's really what your teacher did, it's a mistake.

Try e.g. $$ A = \pmatrix{1\cr 0\cr},\ B = \pmatrix{0\cr 2\cr},\
C^{-1} = \pmatrix{5 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}$$